# Returning a Column Header which Corresponds to a Maximum Value in a Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
case    inc_date    is1     is5     is10    im1     im5     im10
686     6/8/1972    0.141   0.300   0.149   0.134   0.135   0.142
950     6/1/1945    0.160   0.345   0.172   0.088   0.096   0.138
1005    10/16/1945  0.164   0.261   0.151   0.131   0.261   0.133
1005    11/12/1947  0.146   0.310   0.182   0.112   0.129   0.121
1180    10/9/1945   0.159   0.278   0.134   0.141   0.138   0.150
```

I would like to find out the maximum(s) in each row and return the column name for which the value(s) are the maximum. For example, for the above dataframe, it'd return:

```
686 is5
950 is5
1005 is5, im5
1005 is5
1180 is5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [idxmax](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with `axis=1` to find the column with the greatest value on each row:

```
1 is5
2 is5
3 is5
4 is5
5 is5
```

To create the new column 'Max', use `df['Max'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)`.

To find the row index at which the maximum value occurs in each column, use `df.idxmax()` (or equivalently `df.idxmax(axis=0)`).

---

For 2nd highest, you can use
`df.apply(lambda x: df.index[x.argsort()[::-1][1]], axis=1)`

Comment: IMO `idxmax(1)` - is the most idiomatic way to find the maximum element in the row - +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach:

```
In [96]: cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('^i[sm]')]

In [97]: cols
Out[97]: Index(['is1', 'is5', 'is10', 'im1', 'im5', 'im10'], dtype='object')

In [98]: mask = df[cols].eq(df[cols].max(1), axis=0)

In [99]: mask
Out[99]:
     is1   is5   is10    im1    im5   im10
0  False  True  False  False  False  False
1  False  True  False  False  False  False
2  False  True  False  False   True  False
3  False  True  False  False  False  False
4  False  True  False  False  False  False

In [104]: df[['case']].join(mask.apply(lambda r: ', '.join(cols[r]), axis=1).to_frame('idx'))
Out[104]:
   case       idx
0   686       is5
1   950       is5
2  1005  is5, im5
3  1005       is5
4  1180       is5
```